# Add Rows and Data in Specific Cells with Multithread run - ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, swing, jtable, indexoutofboundsexception, abstracttablemodel

I'm trying to run an app that shows the result of the 4 elapsed time of 4 cars in a `JTable`.

So I'm looking for **update the cell of the faster car** first meanwhile, the other cars are arriving by the time by a `sleep`ing via threads.

Each thread run the result of the elapsed time for each car, but my problem is when I'm trying to add the result to a `JTable`.

I'm coding through a extended `AbstractTableModel`, implemented in my `JTable` of my main class.

I tried to create a `Object[][]` to add the data indexed of every single elapsed time. But when leave it blank or adding some default code, this data is not showed in my `JTable`.

```
public void run() {

  double abs = 0;                 // absolute value of lap
  int rowCount = 0;

        // Loop for laps (Array{1,2,3,4})
        for(int lap = 1; lap < laps.length+1; lap++){
            Thread.sleep((int)(this.car.getElapsedTime() * 1000));       // Sleep method(MILLISECONDS) for Car EnlapsedTime
            abs = abs + this.car.getElapsedTime();                       // Absolute time sum

            newModel.setValueAt(abs, rowCount, this.car.getIdCars());
            rowCount = rowCount + 1;
            newModel.fireTableCellUpdated(rowCount, this.car.getIdCars());
}


class DynamicTable extends AbstractTableModel {

    Car LotusElise = new Car(1, "Lotus Elise", 189, 901);
    Car FerrariCalifornia = new Car(2, "Ferrari California", 483, 1735);
    Car LamborguiniAventador = new Car(3, "Lamborguini Aventador", 691, 1731);
    Car MaseratiMCStradale = new Car(4, "Maserati MC Stradale", 450, 1931);

    private String[] columnNames = {LotusElise.getName(), FerrariCalifornia.getName(), LamborguiniAventador.getName(),
        MaseratiMCStradale.getName()};

    private Object[][] data = {
// adding this code crash the program by the same Exception - this is an example of one lap
//            {LotusElise.getIdCars(), LotusElise.getElapsedTime()},
//            {FerrariCalifornia.getIdCars(), FerrariCalifornia.getElapsedTime()}, 
//            {LamborguiniAventador.getIdCars(), LamborguiniAventador.getElapsedTime()},
//            {MaseratiMCStradale.getIdCars(), MaseratiMCStradale.getElapsedTime()}
    };

    public String getColumnName(int col) {
        return columnNames[col];
    }

    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
        return data[row][col];
    }

public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
    data[row][col] = value;
    fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
```

Under this part of code, I'm running throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0` which `0 = rowCount`. I understand that I don't have any rows from the beginning, but I don't know how add one to this. Probably with `Vector<Double>`?

In this point, I'm having trouble Overriding the `int get value at(int row, int col)` to return indexing from the  `Vector<Double>`, because with `Object[][]` returns `[col][row]`.

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).